# Receiving binary data via HTTP in Go

Tags: api, rest, binary, go, binary-data

What's the best way to go about receiving binary data via HTTP in go?  In my case, I'd like to send a zip file to my application's REST API.  Examples specific to goweb would be great, but net/http is fine too.

Comment: How do you mean with "go about receiving", are you referring to how to best implement it and parse it in GO, or are you referring to how to best send it in a RESTful manner?

Comment: How best to implement and parse it in Go, though any opinions on RESTful best practices would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just read it from the request body

Something like

```
package main

import ("fmt";"net/http";"io/ioutil";"log")

func h(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    buf, err := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
    if err!=nil {log.Fatal("request",err)}
    fmt.Println(buf) // do whatever you want with the binary file buf
}
```

A more reasonable approach is to copy the file into some stream

```
defer req.Body.Close()
f, err := ioutil.TempFile("", "my_app_prefix")
if err!=nil {log.Fatal("cannot open temp file", err)}
defer f.Close()
io.Copy(f, req.Body)
```

Comment: Note that this particular way of handling reads the whole request body into memory. In the real world, you probably want to limit the size, store the data on disk, or something else.

Comment: Limiting it would be wise, but I was mostly interested in an example to educate myself.